# "Navigator is not defined" JSHint, forecast API with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, adobe-brackets, navigator

For a school assignment we have to build a small app prototype which interfaces with the Forecast.io api. I have little experience with APIs but everything in the code seems to be clean and okay.

However, in Brackets, JSHint keeps telling me "Navigator not defined (W117)". Furthermore, console.log statements don't work in several functions and the browser doesn't ask me to share my location. I tried copying exact code and had the same reults.

None of the console logs in the file return anything, I have no way of checking if my browser even gets location data.

```
//JSON declareren
(function () {
    'use strict';
    /*global $, jQuery, console, alert*/
    //Variabelen invoegen
    var latitude, longitude, url, App, myApp, day, days, month, months, year, years, dateTime, getTest, date, Location, myLocation;


App = function () {
    this.getLocation = function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log("Geofix werk");
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.updateWeather);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation fix fail");

        }
    };

    this.updateWeather = function (posn) {
        console.log("Position OK");
        latitude = posn.coords.latitude;
        longitude = posn.coords.longitude;
        console.log(latitude);
        console.log(longitude);

        url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/412e0bc4cc3095a2de7d0bdf663f4e3e/" + latitude + ',' + longitude + "?units=si";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                date = new Date();
                getTest = date.getDate();
                day = date.getDay();
                month = date.getMonth();
                year = date.getFullYear();

                //arrays invoegen
                days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

                months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

            }
        });
    };
};

myLocation = new App();
myLocation.getCurrentLocation();

}());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `navigator` to the `/*global ...` list, the JSHint error should go away.

Try changing the code at the bottom to `myLocation.getLocation();` so it correctly matches the function name you're creating above (`this.getLocation = ...`).

Also, you're mixing `alert()` and `console.log()`. Don't forget that `console.log()` doesn't show popup messages the way `alert()` does. You need to have your browser's developer tools open in order to see console messages. Dev tools open also tell you about other errors that could happen in your code, so it's a good habit to keep them open *any* time you're testing your code anyway.